# How to count words in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

How can I count the number of words in a *bookdown* document?

(I've tried knitting to PDF and then counting the words in the PDF, but solutions for that are surprisingly unwieldy for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wordcountaddin::word_count('bookdown-demo.Rmd')
```

`wordcountaddin` is an RStudio add-in. When you knit a bookdown set of files, such as the bookdown-demo, it combines them into `bookdown-demo.Rmd`, so you can call `wordcountaddin::word_count` on that.  The count ignores YAML and other code chunks and inline code. Also, because References are not included in the .Rmd file, the word count won't count those either.

If `bookdown-demo.Rmd` was deleted in the book creation process, you need to add
`delete_merged_file: false`
to
`_bookdown.yml`